# How to solve AdMob's Adaptive Banner abnormal height?

Tags: android, kotlin, admob, ads, banner-ads

I published my app with AdMob Banner since 2018. On 2020, I changed the banner into Adaptive Banner. On my latest release, I am having an issue with it.

The Adaptive Banner takeover screen with wrong height

[image]

As shown above, the Adaptive Banner takeover most of the screen with abnormal height for a banner.

Here's my Admob:

```
// ADMOB
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:20.2.0"
```

My MainActivity XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_content_main"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/ad_view_container"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/ad_view_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

My MainActivity.kt

```kt
    @AndroidEntryPoint
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    
        private var adView: AdView? = null
        private var adRequest: AdRequest? = null

        private var initialLayoutComplete = false

        private val adSize: AdSize
            get() {
                val display = windowManager.defaultDisplay
                val outMetrics = DisplayMetrics()
                display.getMetrics(outMetrics)
    
                val density = outMetrics.density
    
                var adWidthPixels = adViewContainer.width.toFloat()
                if (adWidthPixels == 0f) {
                    adWidthPixels = outMetrics.widthPixels.toFloat()
                }
    
                val adWidth = (adWidthPixels / density).toInt()
                return AdSize.getCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSize(this, adWidth)
            }

        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            ...
            admobSetup()
            ...
        }

        private fun adMobSetup() {
            if (adViewContainer.visibility == View.GONE)
                adViewContainer.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            
            adRequest = setAdRequest()

            MobileAds.initialize(this) { }
            initAdViewAndLoadBanner()
        }

        private fun initAdViewAndLoadBanner() {

            adView = AdView(this)
            adViewContainer.removeAllViews()
            adViewContainer.addView(adView)

            adViewContainer.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener {
                if (!initialLayoutComplete) {
                    initialLayoutComplete = true
                    loadBanner()
                }
            }
        }

        private fun loadBanner() {

            adView?.adUnitId = getString(R.string.AD_UNIT_ID)

            adView?.adSize = adSize

            // Start loading the ad in the background.
            adView?.loadAd(adRequest!!)
        }
    }
```

By the way, I am using DataBinding, not sure if their is an issue linked to it. Any solution for this?